# assertThat vs assertEquals for big String comparison

Tags: junit4

Everyone says that we should use the new `assertThat` from Junit, but, for big Strings comparison it's seems to be some lack of feature.

Example:

```
@Test
public void testAssertThat() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertThat("auiehaeiueahuiheauihaeuieahuiaehuieahuaiehiaueheauihaeuihaeuiaehuiaehuiaehuiaehaeuihaei",
            CoreMatchers.equalTo( "auiehaeiueahuiheauihaeuieahuiaehuieaheaiehiaueheauihaeuihaeuiaehuiaehuiaehuiaehaeuihaei" ) );
}

@Test
public void testAssertEquals() throws Exception {
    Assert.assertEquals( "auiehaeiueahuiheauihaeuieahuiaehuieahuaiehiaueheauihaeuihaeuiaehuiaehuiaehuiaehaeuihaei",
            "auiehaeiueahuiheauihaeuieahuiaehuieaheaiehiaueheauihaeuihaeuiaehuiaehuiaehuiaehaeuihaei" );
}
```

`assertEquals` prints an easier to read error message:

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
>   expected:<...uihaeuieahuiaehuieah[u]aiehiaueheauihaeuiha...> but
>   was:<...uihaeuieahuiaehuieah[e]aiehiaueheauihaeuiha...>

while `assertThat` prints this:

> java.lang.AssertionError:  Expected:
>   "auiehaeiueahuiheauihaeuieahuiaehuieaheaiehiaueheauihaeuihaeuiaehuiaehuiaehuiaehaeuihaei"
>        but: was "auiehaeiueahuiheauihaeuieahuiaehuieahuaiehiaueheauihaeuihaeuiaehuiaehuiaehuiaehaeuihaei"

Is there a way to get the same behavior with `assertThat`?

Comment: Have you tried ``assertThat(actual, is(equalTo(expected)))``?

Comment: Maybe you can somehow use Groovy PowerAssert.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want one more assertion library

Comment: The friendly message 'org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected comes from the fact that you it is the way that JUnit works with assertEquals and with String as input. 
In this way, Junit throws org.junit.ComparisonFailure. It's the JUnit friendly string comparison exception.
AssertThat has a different semantic and the javadoc explains it explicitely : 
If you want keep the friendly message, you should go on using AssertEquals for String comparison.

Comment: No, assertThat produces a much more friendly message!

It shows both values, expected and actual without any cuts and it is perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The friendly message `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected...` comes from the fact that it is the way that JUnit works with assertEquals and with String as input. 
In this way, Junit throws org.junit.ComparisonFailure if the String comparison fails.

In your IDE, the comparison is more readable indeed. For example, in Eclipse, you can double- click on the failed Junit test to display a string comparison.

Like this :

[image]

AssertThat has a different semantic and the javadoc says it explicitly : 
`Asserts that actual satisfies the condition specified by matcher. If not, an AssertionError is thrown with information about the matcher and failing value.`
And as the name implies, AssertionError has a semantic wider.

To conclude : if you want keep the friendly message for String, you should go on using AssertEquals for String comparisons.